# No cast the polymer elements

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In principal HTML page: **index.html**

```dart
<poly-container a="Hi">
    <poly-item b="hi"></poly-item>
</poly-container>
```

In Polymer HTML definition: **polycontainer.html**

```html
<poly-container>
    <template> ...
        <content></content>
    </template> 
</poly-container>
```

In Dart class: **polycontainer.dart** ...Have tag `<content>` for render external DOM; ...and the 2 classes: PolyContainer and PolyItem

```dart
  processList() // calling from PolyContainer Constructor;
  {
      PolyItem cl;  
      HtmlElement a;

      ContentElement cont=shadowRoot.querySelector('content');
      List<Node> chil=cont.getDistributedNodes();

      for (var i=0; i < chil.length; i++) {  
         if ( chil[i].nodeName == 'POLY-ITEM' ) {   
           a=chil[i];  // (1)  
           cl=chil[i] as PolyItem; // (2)
           cl=a as PolyItem; // (3)
         }
         chil[i].remove();
      }
  }
```

(1) Cast OK; (chil[i] is type Node and "a" is type HtmlElement (Node->Element->HtmlElement)

(2)* Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'PolyItem' in type cast.

(3)* Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'PolyItem' in type cast.

Option 2 and 3 tested at different times.

I thought if we need to start some variable or call a function in the PolyItem constructor.
Someone tried to cast an extended class PolymerElement?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Just set a breakpoint and run your app. The debugger stops at the breakpoint and shows you information like type and value or the variables in scope.
You can also add `print(chil[i]);` which usually gives information about the type (if you don't use DartEditor or the debugger doesn't work which still happens sometimes).

You should post the entire code of you `PolyContainer` element `HTML` and `Dart`.
If it contains code that doesn't have anything to do with the problem create a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem and post this code.